# Install tomcat with Puppet without using inbuilt class

Tags: tomcat, puppet

I am creating a module which installs tomcat using puppet but should not use any of the inbuilt classes of puppet, like I dont want to use tomcat::instance, tomcat::service etc. in my module, I also dont want to use command line installation. What can be the approach for this?

Comment: Please note that `tomcat::instance` etc. are no builtins - they are part of Forge modules. If you want to build your own using just the primitives of Puppet, you will have to figure out 1. how you would do it without Puppet and then 2. how to implement this in a manifest. If you share (1), this might be answerable, although the question is likely too broad for SO.

Comment: If I talk about your 1) point I can write a shell script which will achieve the requirement, so this means all the forge modules are first written in some language like java or some script and then are being used, is it?? For puppet, which language is needed to write forge modules?

Comment: First and foremost, you use the Puppet DSL (manifests). Some management tasks are implemented through Puppet plugins, which are written in Ruby. These will often rely on external tools, written in any language. You could start by sifting through some existing `tomcat` modules. The code is usually visible on GitHub.